# Unstacking data frame not working all the time

Tags: python, pandas

I am puzzled. I have two data frames and I want to unstack them. The first data frame works perfectly..

df:

```
"",Measurement data name,Speed
0,100UM_S304_T6.3_F3400_P-2.5_G1.4_D100_X012820_S2,4.845373130234829
1,100UM_S304_T6.3_F3400_P-2.5_G1.4_D100_X012820_S3,4.263109524556444
2,100UM_S304_T6.3_F3400_P-2.5_G1.4_D100_X012820_S4,4.477553508022049
3,100UM_S304_T6.3_F3400_P-3.0_G1.4_D100_X012820_S2,4.225669481330404
4,100UM_S304_T6.3_F3400_P-3.0_G1.4_D100_X012820_S3,3.964186569036525
5,100UM_S304_T6.3_F3400_P-3.0_G1.4_D100_X012820_S4,4.381883773694611
6,100UM_S304_T6.3_F3400_P-3.5_G1.4_D100_X012820_S2,4.4611936089867035
7,100UM_S304_T6.3_F3400_P-3.5_G1.4_D100_X012820_S3,4.011543928072122
8,100UM_S304_T6.3_F3400_P-3.5_G1.4_D100_X012820_S4,4.760764146212687
```

-

```
new_df = (df.join(df['Measurement data name'].str.rsplit('_', 1, expand=True))
          .set_index([0, 1])
          .drop('Measurement data name', axis=1)
            .unstack(1))
new_cols = [('{1} {0}'.format(*tup)) for tup in new_df.columns]
new_df.columns = new_cols
final_df = new_df.reset_index()
final_df = final_df.rename(columns={0: 'Measurement data name'})
```

final_df:

```
"",Measurement data name,S2 Speed,S3 Speed,S4 Speed
0,100UM_S304_T6.3_F3400_P-2.5_G1.4_D100_X012820,4.845373130234829,4.263109524556444,4.477553508022049
1,100UM_S304_T6.3_F3400_P-3.0_G1.4_D100_X012820,4.225669481330404,3.964186569036525,4.381883773694611
2,100UM_S304_T6.3_F3400_P-3.5_G1.4_D100_X012820,4.4611936089867035,4.011543928072122,4.760764146212687
```

The second data frame doesn't work the same..

df:

```
"",Measurement data name,Speed
0,VR-20200211_161131_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P0.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519_S2,11.157404940816864
1,VR-20200211_161321_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P0.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519_S3,10.167709975092029
2,VR-20200211_161454_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P0.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519_S4,9.888377066223338
3,VR-20200211_162028_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P-2.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519_S2,7.240216451403143
4,VR-20200211_175514_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P-2.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519_S3,8.311288630510798
5,VR-20200212_090341_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P-2.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519_S4,7.6884571127601555
```

-

```
new_df = (df.join(df['Measurement data name'].str.rsplit('_', 1, expand=True))
          .set_index([0, 1])
          .drop('Measurement data name', axis=1)
            .unstack(1))
new_cols = [('{1} {0}'.format(*tup)) for tup in new_df.columns]
new_df.columns = new_cols
final_df = new_df.reset_index()
final_df = final_df.rename(columns={0: 'Measurement data name'})
```

final_df:

```
"",Measurement data name,S2 Speed,S3 Speed,S4 Speed
0,VR-20200211_161131_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P0.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519,11.157404940816864,,
1,VR-20200211_161321_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P0.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519,,10.167709975092029,
2,VR-20200211_161454_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P0.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519,,,9.888377066223338
3,VR-20200211_162028_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P-2.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519,7.240216451403143,,
4,VR-20200211_175514_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P-2.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519,,8.311288630510798,
5,VR-20200212_090341_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P-2.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519,,,7.6884571127601555
```

Any ideas why?? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the `Measurement data names` in your second dataframe is unique, even after you remove the `speed` component. it looks like the time-of-day component that is giving uniqueness to the measurement data names.

```
# from df2['Measurement data names']
VR-20200211_161131_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P0.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519_S2
VR-20200211_161321_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P0.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519_S3
VR-20200211_161454_A5052_T6.2_F3200_P0.0_G1.3_50UM_X111519_S4
            ^^^^^^
...
```